# Should stubs be writtnen before or after unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I was discussing this with a friend, and while intuitively it would seem to make no difference, I was wondering if anyone here might come up with a good reason to write the stub before or after the unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't really matter, as long as in the end you have both so the code compiles (or, in the case of interpreted languages, doesn't raise a *method not found* error).

However, since this is **test-driven** development, it makes sense to focus on these and write them first. Sometimes, even if I have a clear idea of how I want to structure my code, only while writing the tests do I realise that the API is useless and end up changing it. Writing the stubs after having written the tests makes this more easy.

Comment: "Sometimes, even if I have a clear idea of how I want to structure my code, only while writing the tests do I realise that the API is useless and end up changing it."

Doesn't that mean it makes more sense to write stubs first? Since it takes literally no time to write or change one compared to writing or changing a test?

Comment: No, because I will only really know the interface of the function _after_ having written the test, because whilst writing the test I may realise that it might be easier to do things differently. Writing stubs isn't that hard really, so it's best to defer doing so until you know exactly what your functions are called and what they do, and that would be after you have written the tests.

Comment: But how can you write a test without knowing the interface of the function? I thought the first step of TDD was figuring that out.

Comment: Yes, of course. But as I said, while implementing the test you may realise that the interface you came up with is a little awkward to use (especially in languages like C, where you have to worry about who will own what, if you pass it as a pointer or the whole thing, and how to signal errors) you may end up changing your mind about it, and then it's annoying if you have already written a stub that no longer works because the interface changed, making it more useful to do that as a last step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing TDD, you will write your tests first and concurrently implement any required test infrastructure such as stubs so that you will be able to do state-based verification on the stubs after you exercise your test subject (also known as System Under Test or SUT).

Hard for me to envision writing stubs before the tests that will need them, but maybe that could work better for you--anyway, it can be difficult to grasp TDD as a style of working, so my advice is to keep at it and figure out what works best for you.

Personally, I hardly ever think of stubs anyway, as testing with mocks is they way I like to work (behavior-based verification rather than state-based). You don't mention what tools you are using; perhaps a good toolkit for mock objects isn't readily available for your tools (although I doubt you'd have trouble finding something for most languages now). Still, I can think of quite a few mock object libraries for, say, Java work and really I only have patience for one or two of them, so again it makes sense to experiment and discover what you like best.